# mongo spring how to sort the result based on value in nested array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having documents in mongodb like below

```
{  
   "_id":"993208_1",
   "clientId":"1",
   "searchQueryAnalysisObj":[  
      {  
         "searchKeyword":"coat",
         "searchKeywordScore":0.7,
         "searchAnalysisModifiedDate": ISODate("2018-08-20T11:53:08.228Z")
      },
      {  
         "searchKeyword":"wire",
         "searchKeywordScore":1.2,
         "searchAnalysisModifiedDate":ISODate("2018-09-20T11:53:08.228Z")
      }
   ],
   "_class":"com.client.model.MainClickStreamData"
}
```

I can have multiple objects within searchQueryAnalysis object .which contains searchKeyword , searchKeywordScore and searchAnalysisModifiedDate .

I want to sort my result based on the value of searchKeywordScore spring query , such that the largest value of searchKeywordScore  in any searchQueryAnalysis,  I will get that document as first , like that I want to get top 10 records .

I am trying to sort it as

```
Query clientData = new Query(Criteria.where("clientId").is(clientId));
            clientData.with(new Sort(new Order(Direction.DESC, "searchKeywordScore")));

    List<ClickNavigationBrandData> allProcessedClicks = mongoOperation.find(clientData, ClickNavigationBrandData.class);
```

But could not do.

Could anyone help me doing this ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the documents to the post instead of link/image ? Also please add your attempts too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have soled this problem -

```
> Query clientData = new Query(Criteria.where("clientId").is(clientId));
>           clientData.with(new Sort(Direction.DESC,
> "searchQueryAnalysisObj.searchKeywordScore"));
>           clientData.limit(10);
```